# Proof of recurrence relation with induction

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations, proof-explanation, recursion

I have defined the following recurrence relation:

$$D(k+1) = 2D(k) + (-1)^{k+1}$$ with the base case D(1) = 1

I need help proving, through ***induction***, that this relation is given by:

$$D(n) = \frac{1}{3} (2^{n+1} + (-1)^n) $$

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I'm stuck on the induction step and proving that D(k) implies D(k+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induction step hypothesis is $D(n) = \frac{1}{3} \left(2^{n+1} + (-1)^n\right)\,$. Then:

$$
\begin{align}
D(n+1) & =2D(n)+(-1)^{n+1} && \quad\quad\quad \text{by the recurrence relation} \\
 & = \frac{2}{3} \left(2^{n+1} + (-1)^n\right)+(-1)^{n+1} && \quad\quad\quad \text{by the induction hypothesis } \\
 & = \frac{2}{3} \,2^{n+1} + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{-1} +(-1)^{n+1} \\
 & = \frac{1}{3} \,2^{n+2} + \left(1-\frac{2}{3}\right) \,(-1)^{n+1} \\
 & = \frac{1}{3} \left( \,2^{n+2} + (-1)^{n+1} \right) && \quad\quad\quad \text{which proves the induction step}\\
\end{align}
$$